# Graphql query logs a number in console

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am at the very first point of making an app with gatsby-strapi toolchain and as usual, I want to log the query data on the console. But for some reason, only a number is logged. The query works properly in Graphql dashboard (http://localhost:8000/___graphql) and also it can be printed in the DOM. What is that number? What is going on?
Here is the code:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
const IndexPage = ({data}) => (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Home" />
    <h1>Hi people</h1>
    <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage

export const pageQuery = graphql`
query MyQuery {
  allStrapiCategory {
    edges {
      node {
        createdAt
        name
      }
    }
    totalCount
  }
}
`
console.log("Returned data: "+ pageQuery)
```

Graphql dashboard returns this (and though the query has something to return):

```
{
  "data": {
    "allStrapiCategory": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "createdAt": "2020-07-17T14:22:19.752Z",
            "name": "music-history",
            "id": "Category_5f11b41b2a43a66a84b0ac5c"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "createdAt": "2020-07-17T14:48:40.595Z",
            "name": "education",
            "id": "Category_5f11ba48725ad26f9aed7aee"
          }
        }
      ],
      "totalCount": 2
    }
  }
}
```

This result would also be printed out in the DOM (inside that div).
And finally, this is what the console logs:

Returned data: 1435490915

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're GraphQL data will be injected into you page through props. Try logging this out instead and you should see the result of the GraphQL query.

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
const IndexPage = ({data}) => {
console.log("Returned data: "+ data)
return (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Home" />
    <h1>Hi people</h1>
    <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
  </Layout>
)
}

export default IndexPage

export const pageQuery = graphql`
query MyQuery {
  allStrapiCategory {
    edges {
      node {
        createdAt
        name
      }
    }
    totalCount
  }
}
`
```

The reason why you are seeing a number logged when executing `console.log("Returned data: "+ pageQuery)` is probably because the Gatsby internals converts the graphql tagged template literal into a number for internal usage.

Comment: That's right. The data lives inside the component. Thank you :) @Robert Cooper